What is this Nintendo 64 DD flyswatter game from?
At 4:57 of DidYouKnowGaming's video on rumored Mario games, the background footage shows a flyswatter minigame in a bedroom with a Nintendo 64 DD playing Super Mario 64. At the time, they were discussing the Mario Artist games. A caption in the corner credited the footage to YouTube user LuigiBlood. However, I could not find the footage on their channel.
What game is this flyswatter footage from?
https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkxj191G7kj9ur7Wnwf47GAKzZkrvX1vidz


Mario Paint had a flyswatter game, but it didn't look like this.

It appears to be from a mini game called Gnat Attack that appeared in an early prototype build of Mario Artist: Paint Studio, but was removed from the final product.
Same scene is shown here on a page to listen to the music from the level.
According to this blog post, there were 4 levels which looped into harder versions until it crashed.
I also found this video by LuigiBlood, which has a showcase of the mini game, which appears to be where the footage DidYouKnowGaming used was found.
